# Killing Previous Route's Controller On Next Route

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, routes, angularjs-scope

I'm having an issue in my Angular app where if I arrive at one controller view which makes an `$http.get()` asynchonous call and navigate away to a different controller view before the promise can resolve then I effectively end up having functions from one controller executing while on a completely different controller.

For example if the first page does an `$http.get()` and then calls `$window.location = data.goToUrl` in the `.success()` function. Then if I open that first page, and navigate away before the `.success()` fires then when I arrive on the completely different page I was navigating to then when the first page's `.success()` method eventually fires off I will be navigated away from the new page which should never be navigating me anywhere normally.

How can I either cancel all promises or kill all asynchronous functions of a controller when I leave that controller to make sure it doesn't affect the next view? Or is there a better way of handling this issue?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't cancel requests which are already started. You should find another way to solve the problem, for example you can disable the button which is handling route by using `ng-disable` until your promise is rejected or resolved.